Why does pre-trained Swin Transformer encoder fail on TPU but works on CPU in Colab?
I’m working on an image segmentation task and trying to use a pre-trained Swin Transformer Large (Swin-L) encoder for the feature extraction backbone. The code runs perfectly on a CPU in Colab. However, when switching to a TPU, it throws the error shown below.
The Code:
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, Input
from tfswin import SwinTransformerLarge224


def load_swin_encoder(input_shape=(512, 512, 3)):
    # Load pre-trained Swin-L model
    swin_encoder = SwinTransformerLarge224(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                                           input_shape=input_shape)

    # Freeze the pre-trained layers
    for layer in swin_encoder.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Extract outputs from the four stages
    stage_outputs = [
        swin_encoder.get_layer('normalize').output,  # Output from the 0 stage
        swin_encoder.get_layer('layers.0').output,   # Output from the first stage
        swin_encoder.get_layer('layers.1').output,   # Output from the second stage
        swin_encoder.get_layer('layers.2').output,   # Output from the third stage
        swin_encoder.get_layer('layers.3').output,   # Output from the fourth stage
    ]
    return Model(swin_encoder.input, stage_outputs, name="SwinTransformerEncoder")


# Test Code
encoder = load_swin_encoder(input_shape=(512, 512, 3))
dummy_input = tf.random.uniform((1, 512, 512, 3))
encoder_outputs = encoder(dummy_input)

for i, output in enumerate(encoder_outputs):
    print(f"Stage {i + 1} output shape: {output.shape}")


The Error:
The code throws the following error on TPU:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3cb122d32678> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # loading Sanity check
----> 2 encoder = load_swin_encoder(input_shape=(512, 512, 3))
      3 dummy_input = tf.random.uniform((1, 512, 512, 3))
      4 encoder_outputs = encoder(dummy_input)
      5 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    117         for x in flat_inputs:
    118             if not isinstance(x, backend.KerasTensor):
--> 119                 raise ValueError(
    120                     "All `inputs` values must be KerasTensors. Received: "
    121                     f"inputs={inputs} including invalid value {x} of "

ValueError: All `inputs` values must be KerasTensors. Received: inputs=KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_4'), name='input_4', description="created by layer 'input_4'") including invalid value KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_4'), name='input_4', description="created by layer 'input_4'") of type <class 'tf_keras.src.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>


Question:
Why does this code work on a CPU but fail on a TPU in Colab? How can I fix this issue to make it compatible with TPU execution?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This does not seem like Hardware accelerator - GPU/TPU error as I tried replicating the same using Google Colab by selecting the available - CPU/GPU and TPU and did not notice any issue. Please find the replicated gist for the same.
Please try again by installing the latest Tensorflow 2.18 and Keras 3.7 version and let us know if the issues still persists. Thank you.
